# User privileges with mysql database and php

Tags: php, mysql, privileges

I'm making a login page well i've actually finished the login but how would i go about having the web page display diffren't things based on a users privileges and how would i set the privileges in my mysql database? and then use them in my php code?

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin installed? Also mysql workbench will help you write queries and setup your schema.

Comment: Yes i have phpmyadmin and i will get mysql workbench

Comment: Have you done a successful `mysql_connect` to the mysql database from php?

Comment: Yes, I've got a perfectly working log in . I just need to know how to separate certain users by their privileges

Comment: Do you have a table for users yet?

Comment: Yeah otherwise i wouldnt have a working login would i ? not saying that in a rude or sarcastic tone but as a question

Comment: You could have the users defined in the php code, but that's the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually make a field in the `users` table called `admin` or in this case maybe `privilege_level`, then in your php, you define what values of that field correspond to what levels of privilege.

EDIT (example):

```
// start session on every page using $_SESSION array
session_start();
session_name("Your Site Name");
header("Cache-control: private");

// in login file:
$q = mysql_query("SELECT uid, privilege_level FROM users WHERE pw = 'escaped_and_preferrably_hashed_password' AND username = 'escaped_username' LIMIT 0,1");

// if row found:
if($q && mysql_num_rows($q) > 0){

    // get associative array
    $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

    // set session vars
    $_SESSION['privilege_level'] = $array['privilege_level'];

}
```

Then, on pages where you want to check the privilege level you can use a switch or other control structure/design pattern to load content dynamically, ie:

```
switch($_SESSION['privilege_level']){
    default:
        echo 'you have no privileges';
    break;
    case "1":
        echo 'you have some privileges';
    break;
    case "2":
        echo 'you have lots of privileges';
    break;
}
```

Comment: So once i connect to my database and select that table and the field privilege_level then what would i do ? could you give me a code example of this ? i'm kind of new to this. Thanks :)

Comment: Your example is better than mine +1

Comment: Sorry its been a couple days but how are the privilege levels default, 1 and 2 set ?

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs on they are giving a username/password. The database should store this username and a hash of the password. For Ex.`md5($password)`. You first do a query like `"SELECT privilege_level FROM table WHERE username = ".mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["username"])." AND password=".md5($_POST["password"])`

Then save that privilege_level to the session. `$_SESSION["privilege_level"] = $privilege_level`

Now when they load the next page, that page should refer to the privilege level in session variable to construct the page.